# Cabal: can't install gloss-raster because of LLVM

Tags: llvm, cabal

`cabal install gloss-raster` outputs:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring gloss-raster-1.7.4.3...
Building gloss-raster-1.7.4.3...
Preprocessing library gloss-raster-1.7.4.3...
[1 of 2] Compiling Graphics.Gloss.Raster.Array ( Graphics/Gloss/Raster/Array.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Gloss/Raster/Array.o )
Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
         Make sure you have installed LLVM
ghc: could not execute: opt-3.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
gloss-raster-1.7.4.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I've installed LLVM (`apt-get install llvm`) and its Haskell libraries (`cabal install llvm`), so what's wrong with LLVM?

I tried installing a specific version with `sudo cabal install llvm-3.0` an I got:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: llvm (user goal)
rejecting: llvm-3.0.1.0/installed-d41..., 3.0.1.0, 3.0.0.0, 0.10.0.1,
0.10.0.0, 0.9.1.2, 0.9.1.1, 0.9.1.0, 0.9.0.1, 0.8.2.0, 0.8.1.0, 0.8.0.2,
0.7.1.2, 0.7.1.1, 0.7.1.0, 0.7.0.1, 0.7.0.0, 0.6.8.0, 0.6.7.0, 0.6.6.0,
0.6.5.0, 0.6.4.0, 0.6.3.0, 0.6.2.0, 0.6.0.3, 0.6.0.2, 0.5.0.1, 0.4.4.2,
0.4.4.1, 0.4.2.0, 0.4.1.0, 0.4.0.3, 0.4.0.1, 0.4.0.0, 0.0.2 (global constraint
requires ==3.0)
```

Comment: `opt-3.0` suggest you need llvm 3.0. Which version do you have? You might also need to install `llvm-dev`.

Comment: I edited the first post. Installing `llvm-dev` didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the LLVM compiler so that GHC can use it, but the gloss library doesn't need the Haskell LLVM library.

If your "apt-get install llvm" installed the LLVM optimiser as 'opt' instead of 'opt-3.0' then you may need to manually add a link "ln -s" from opt -> opt-3.0

Comment: I already have `opt` in `/usr/bin` which points to `opt-2.9` in `/usr/bin` which points to `opt` in `/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/bin/opt`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bug in gloss-raster - it cannot pick the LLVM installed on your system. I'd suggest asking at gloss@ouroborus.net